# Excel Macro to search and replace dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have a macro that is supposed to go through data, search for dates that are not recognized by excel, and change their format so that they're more "excel friendly". When I try to run it, I receive a Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Could someone look through my code and help me recognize the problem?

The dates are formatted "201611 - (November 2016)" and have been imported from a CSV file.

Here is my code

```
Sub TestFind()
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a500")
    Set c = .Find("201* - (*** 201*)", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = .Date(.Left(c.Value, 4), (.Mid(c.Value, 5, 2)), 1)
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the revised code.

The most significant change is from this:

`c.Value = .Date(.Left(c.Value, 4), (.Mid(c.Value, 5, 2)), 1)`

To this:

`c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), (Mid(c.Value, 5, 2)), 1)`

Notice I used the `DateSerial` function to create the date, and removed the dots when calling `DateSerial`, `Left` and `Mid`, as these are functions, not properties.

Here's the complete function:

```
Sub TestFind()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a500")
        Set c = .Find("201* - (*** 201*)", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do While Not c Is Nothing
                c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), (Mid(c.Value, 5, 2)), 1)
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    If c.Address = firstAddress Then Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```